# Writing the function to maximize volume or a cylinder

Tags: functions, polynomials, quadratics

A rectangular piece of paper is curled into a cylinder with two open circles on each side.  The perimeter of the piece of paper is 124 inches.  What is a function that could be written to find the length and width of the paper where the volume of the cylinder is at a maximum?

Comment: Welcome to the Math Stack Exchange.  What have you tried?

Comment: The volume of a cylinder is $V = \pi r^2h$.  How are $r$ and $h$ related to the dimensions of the paper?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints.

The piece of paper is rectangular, so you have two legs for the length $L$ and two legs for the width $W$.  Hence, the perimeter $P=2W+2L$.

You know the perimeter, so you know $2W+2L=124$ (inches).  With this in mind you can solve for $L$ in terms of $W$, or vice versa.

This lets you express the volume of the cylinder in terms of $L$ only, or $W$ only.  Following this, you can use that formula to find the maximum volume (I'd use a derivative) but it doesn't look like you're asked to go that far.

Can you take it from here?